# How to config the electronWinstallerConfig in electron-forge to specify a custom install path for the setup?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

After distributing the project; I get the setup file in the out/make/squirrel.windows/x64 folder at the project root. When I try to install the setup file (CertificatsApp.exe), it actually installs in the Users/User/AppData/Local/CertificatsApp folder by default! But I want to install the setup in a different path.

I tried to set the appDirectory to a custon directory in the package.json file like that, but I didn't work:

```
"electronWinstallerConfig": {
    "name": "CertificatsApp",
    "appDirectory": "/install"
},
```

I got this idea from: https://electronforge.io/config/electronWinstallerConfig

Comment: did you figure this out?